# How to set container with max-width but only from one side?

Tags: html, css, sass

My container looks like this:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1254px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

then I need a container that has the same margin from the left, but from the right it should have none.

I tried something like this however unfortunately it does not work.

```
 .containerFromLeft {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1254px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You have set the width of the FromLeft container twice. Should one of those settings be max-width?

Comment: yes, my mistake, but still not working.

Comment: Could you describe what you want the layout to be? Have you thought of using calc?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/c4mozCC - something like this. I tried, but no clue how to count this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below. I am using `500px` for the demo but you can replace it with your width

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: max(0px, (100% - 500px)/2); /* what you need */
}


/* to compare with the classic configuration */
.box {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="box"></div>
```